# MMDrawerController Subclass in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mmdrawercontroller

**if** you're using Swift + CocoaPods + use_frameworks! with the MMDrawerController opened source (ObjC) library you might have trouble subclassing `MMDrawerController` getting **multiple** warnings of "unused initializer"

All you'll have to do is override the initializers and call super. Pretty easy but I saw that there was absolutely nothing on this issue while Googling for this issue, so I'm just trying to help out. I've posted my code below.

Comment: This should serve as a helper for people Googling for "MMDrawerController+Subclass+Swift" with the question concerning the debugger error of "unused initializers"

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import MMDrawerController

class TRDrawerController: MMDrawerController {

    private var recordsModel = TRRecordsModel.sharedInstanceOfRecordsModel
    private var itemsModel = TRItemsModel.sharedInstanceOfItemsModel

    init() {
        let centerViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "TRMain", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TRTrackerViewController") as! TRTrackerViewController
        centerViewController.recordsModel = recordsModel
        centerViewController.itemsModel = itemsModel
        let firstNavigationController = TRNavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        let rightViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "TRMain", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TRSettingsViewController") as! TRSettingsViewController
        rightViewController.recordsModel = recordsModel
        centerViewController.itemsModel = itemsModel
        let secondNavigationController = TRNavigationController(rootViewController: rightViewController)

        super.init(centerViewController: firstNavigationController, leftDrawerViewController: nil, rightDrawerViewController: secondNavigationController)
        self.openDrawerGestureModeMask = [.PanningCenterView]
        self.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = [.PanningCenterView, .TapCenterView, .TapNavigationBar]
        self.shouldStretchDrawer = false
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    // Won't be utilizing this, I want the app to crash if this gets used
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```